# Pi 2 + camera module = 90 fps - more?

Tags: camera, raspicam

The pi one could do 90 frames/second for high speed photography using the raspberry pi camera module. Can the pi2 get a higher rate with its 3 extra cores + memory ?

Comment: With what camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  As far as I am aware it's the GPU which does all the camera "heavy lifting" and communicates with the camera via the CSI interface.

I'm not sure that the ARM core(s) have any part to play in the image processing so I expect the 90 fps figure would be unchanged.

Of course post-processing may well be improved.  The new cores have NEON which can provide a huge increase in performance for some graphical tasks.

Comment: Indeed; given that the Pi2 has the exact same GPU as the Pi1 there is no speed-up. Even if it were, the Omnivision 5647 sensor (which the camera uses) is only capable of 120fps maximum (at 320x240 resolution) according to its [datasheet](http://www.ovt.com/uploads/parts/OV5647.pdf) so to go beyond this would require a whole new sensor and thus a whole new firmware.